# Since "coordinate time" has a very specific meaning, how to call more general parametrizations?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology

Recently I've learned that ["*coordinate time*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_time) assigned to a particular time-like spacetime path is not only required

(1) to be monotonous and continuous and even differentiable wrt. the "*proper time*" corresponding to that path,

but also that

(2) [*In the special case of an inertial observer in special relativity, by convention the coordinate time at an event is the same as the proper time [...]*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_time).

Is there some common name for a parametrization of the (time-like) spacetime path $\gamma$ of an inertial observer,

$$t_{\gamma} : \gamma \rightarrow \mathbb R,$$

which satisfies condition (1) but not necessarily (2) ?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): A time coordinate should be defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of spacetime $M$, not just along a single curve $\gamma$.

Comment: Qmechanic: "_A time coordinate should be defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of spacetime $M$, not just along a single curve_ $\gamma$" -- My question refers to "_coordinate time_" values only as far as they're attributed to elements of (the image of time-like path) $\gamma$. You may consider any suitable ("larger") definition of "_coordinate time_" which induces such values "along (the image of) $\gamma$", and correspondingly for "_proper time_" values, too. For what it's worth and if it helps you also may consider $\gamma$ to be contained within "_an open neighborhood $U$ of spacetime $M$_".

Comment: Coordinate time isn’t differentiable with respect to proper time of a photon. When a photon travel in an optically dense media, there is a positive (although possibly small) amount of proper time for a unit of coordinate time. But when the photon enters vacuum, increment of its proper time per a unit of coordinate time becomes zero. It isn’t even a continuous function.